# How to authorize Firebase domain to confirm email?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a Web ReactJs app with Firebase and I need to redirect a user to my live site version after

```
doSendEmailVerification = () => this.auth.currentUser.sendEmailVerification({
    url: process.env.REACT_APP_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL_REDIRECT,
  })
```

if set the url to `localhost` it works from the web and local version and I receiving an email with redirect link but if I try to change it to `https://dental2-test.firebaseio.com` I've got this error

> {code: "auth/unauthorized-continue-uri", message: "Domain not
>   whitelisted by project"}

Both are added to the authentication providers domains
[image]

What do I missing?

Comment: I am assuming you are using localhost for testing only. Try to test with your production domain.

Comment: localhost is only use for testing, may you need firebase hosting or other to use.

Comment: I need to make it work with dental2-test.firebaseio.com and it doesn't but work with localhost

Comment: You need to host your website for more information https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler

Comment: You need to whitelist the domain `dental2-test.firebaseio.com`. Currently you only have `dental2-test.firebaseapp.com` whitelisted, based on your screenshot.

Comment: @bojeil you're right! my fault